# Emulate Force Stop from ADB/Shell Commands

Tags: android, shell, adb

Is there a way using the current command line tools (`adb`, `am`, `pm`) to emulate a user pressing Force Stop from the Settings app? Calling `kill <pid>` from the shell only works so well as to emulate what happens when the system kills a process, but Force Stop does more to remove the memory of an application by removing its `ActivityRecord` instances that Android saves around.

Is there a shell command we can call to emulate this same behavior?

Cheers.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use **am**:

```
am force-stop: force stop everything associated with <PACKAGE>.

am kill: Kill all processes associated with <PACKAGE>.  Only kills.
  processes that are safe to kill -- that is, will not impact the user
  experience.
```

for example:

```
adb shell am force-stop <PACKAGE>
```

Comment: Ack, just noticed this on my ICS device.  Any idea when it was introduced?  The version of `am` on my 2.2 devices doesn't have either of these.